# What is this serrated-leaved plant with white-yellow flovers?

Tags: identification

[image]

[image]

[image]

Pictures taken at night, sorry. Zone 7a, continental Europe. Height 1m 20cm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That would be ox-eye daisy (now classified as Leucanthemum vulgare). Note the short petals on the flowers, which is one way to identify the plant.

Photo: http://www.cirrusimage.com/Flower/Ox-eye_daisy.jpg

Photo of leaves (hard to find, and in a funny context): https://i1.wp.com/gathervictoria.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/dscf4091.jpg?ssl=1

I've grown this, and you really don't want to let it go to seed (they spread very readily). Otherwise, it's a well-behaved clumping plant, although it tends to form a large clump very quickly. After it flowers, the flower stalks are rather unsightly, so you have some maintenance in cutting them down, and then the plant is rather boring until the end of the growing season.

Comment: I dont know what to do. Shoul I try to eradicate it, or leave it alone, or try controlling it? The only thing that bothers me about this plant is its ability to spread and colonize the area. It is anyway in a “wild“ part of the garden, so I dont expect a spectacular look. But it may choke the surrounding plants, no?

Comment: If you don't deadhead it, the plant's seeds can easily fill in any spaces you have in the garden (and not just your wild garden, either), just like any weed. If you can deadhead the plant, then its clumping behavior is not likely to choke out its neighbors. It's easy to eradicate, though - no stringy roots or stolons to worry about - a shovel and some time is all that's needed. You could do what I did - I moved a single plant to an easily accessible area, but behind an aster. I enjoyed the daisies in the spring & deadheaded them, and the aster grew tall enough to hide the summer/fall foliage.

Answer (score 2):

Ox-eye Daisy! This plant is both pretty and edible. The leaves taste like black peppercorns and make a great addition to salads.

Edible source:
https://www.ediblewildfood.com/oxeye-daisy.aspx